# php ,mysql image is not displaying from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

image is not displaying from the database it show just showing broken image

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //Update hostname
mysql_select_db("postad", $con); //Update database name
$query = "SELECT path1 FROM img_tbl";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$photo = $row['path1'];
 echo "<center><img src=$photo alt=Profile Photo>";
?>
```

Comment: Please avoid using the _deprecated_ mysql functions

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging, like a `view source` to see the (broken) html you generated? deprecated means "don't use this anymore. it's obsolete and will be removed from PHP in a future version"

Comment: i dont know  how to see

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari: that's broken. `'`-strings don't interpolate variables.

Comment: i have used   
echo '<center>' . '<img src="$photo" alt="Profile Photo">' . '</center>'; but same error

Comment: try to echo out the $photo to make sure the path is correct

Comment: @sainadhreddy try this: `echo '<center><img src= '.$photo.' alt="Profile Photo"> </center>';`

Comment: path is correct but it showing broken image  i tried echo out showing same error

Comment: @HawasKa i have tried echo '<center><img src= '.$photo.' alt="Profile Photo"> </center>';

Comment: @sainadhreddy `echo $photo;` and what do you see?

Comment: @HawaKa echo $photo  showing imagespath1/1443196520.jpg

Comment: @sainadhreddy now do you really have a folder name `imagespath1`? placed in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks HawaKa u showed me solution Thanks a lot

Comment: accept means just clicking tick mark is it

Comment: @sainadhreddy Yep, you did it. Thank you and have a beautiful day! cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from the comments, this is the fix you need:

```
echo '<center><img src= '.$photo.' alt="Profile Photo"></center>';
```

Answer (score 4):

$photo is path right

then try this

```
echo '<center><img src='.$photo.'alt="Profile Photo"></center>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change second last line with this

```
echo '<center><img src="'.$photo.'" alt="Profile Photo"></center>';
```

This will work if $photo path is correct...